# How can I find the Largest Common Substring between two strings in PHP?

Tags: php, algorithm, string, performance, spam-prevention

Is there a fast algorithm for finding the Largest Common Substring in two `strings` or is it an NPComplete problem?

In PHP I can find a needle in a haystack:

```
<?php

if (strstr("there is a needle in a haystack", "needle")) {
    echo "found<br>\n";
}
?>
```

I guess I could do this in a loop over one of the `strings` but that would be very expensive! Especially since my application of this is to search a database of email and look for spam (i.e. similar emails sent by the same person).

Does anyone have any PHP code they can throw out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have since found [a relevant wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem). It is not a NP complete problem, it can be done in O(mn) time using a dynamic programming algorithm.

In PHP I found the [similar_text](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) function very useful. Here's a code sample to retrieve a series of text emails and loop through them and find ones that are 90% similar to each other. **Note: Something like this is NOT scalable**:

```
<?php
// Gather all messages by a user into two identical associative arrays
$getMsgsRes = mysql_query(SELECT * FROM email_messages WHERE from = '$someUserID');
while($msgInfo = mysql_fetch_assoc($getMsgsRes))
{
    $msgsInfo1[] = $msgInfo;
    $msgsInfo2[] = $msgInfo;
}

// Loop over msgs and compare each one to every other
foreach ($msgsInfo1 as $msg1)
    foreach ($msgsInfo2 as $msg2)
        similar_text($msg1['msgTxt'],$msg2['msgTxt'],$similarity_pst);
        if ($similarity_pst > 90)
            echo "{$msg1['msgID']} is ${similarity_pst}% to {$msg2['msgID']}\n";
?>
```

Comment: The answer itself didn't help but the idea solved my problem. Perfect example of using ```similar_text()``` to find similarity between strings

Answer (score 11):

The [similar_text](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) function may be what you want.

This calculates the similarity between two strings. Returns the number of matching chars in both strings

You may also want to look at [levenshtein](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php)

Comment: no, this is not what he wants. those algorithms does not at all calculate longest common substring, why do you even suggest this?

Answer (score 7):

> Especially since my application of this is to search a database of email and look for spam (i.e. similar emails sent by the same person).

I think you should be looking at Bayesian spam inference algorithms, not necessarily longest common substring.

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Implement-Bayesian-inference-using-PHP-Part-1/

Answer (score 6):

I've just wrote a function the finds the longest sub string in str1 that exists in str2

```
public static function getLongestMatchingSubstring($str1, $str2)
{
    $len_1 = strlen($str1);
    $longest = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $len_1; $i++){
        for($j = $len_1 - $i; $j > 0; $j--){
            $sub = substr($str1, $i, $j);
            if (strpos($str2, $sub) !== false && strlen($sub) > strlen($longest)){
                $longest = $sub;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $longest;
}
```

Comment: This is not as fast as the dynamic programming approach (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring#PHP), but it uses much less memory. In my test, the DP approach crashed my PHP comparing two 1200-character strings. Even if I allocate more memory, this is only 6x slower for the same job (6 sec vs. 1 sec).

Comment: In my benchmark this implementation can be up to 1000 !!! as slow as other algorithms (especially with long strings). Be warned.

Answer (score 4):

Late to this party, but here is a way to find the largest common substring in an array of strings:

Example:

```
$array = array(
    'PTT757LP4',
    'PTT757A',
    'PCT757B',
    'PCT757LP4EV'
);
echo longest_common_substring($array); // => T757
```

The function:

```
function longest_common_substring($words) {
    $words = array_map('strtolower', array_map('trim', $words));
    $sort_by_strlen = create_function('$a, $b', 'if (strlen($a) == strlen($b)) { return strcmp($a, $b); } return (strlen($a) < strlen($b)) ? -1 : 1;');
    usort($words, $sort_by_strlen);
    // We have to assume that each string has something in common with the first
    // string (post sort), we just need to figure out what the longest common
    // string is. If any string DOES NOT have something in common with the first
    // string, return false.
    $longest_common_substring = array();
    $shortest_string = str_split(array_shift($words));

    while (sizeof($shortest_string)) {
        array_unshift($longest_common_substring, '');
        foreach ($shortest_string as $ci => $char) {
            foreach ($words as $wi => $word) {
                if (!strstr($word, $longest_common_substring[0] . $char)) {
                    // No match
                    break 2;
                } // if
            } // foreach
            // we found the current char in each word, so add it to the first longest_common_substring element,
            // then start checking again using the next char as well
            $longest_common_substring[0].= $char;
        } // foreach
        // We've finished looping through the entire shortest_string.
        // Remove the first char and start all over. Do this until there are no more
        // chars to search on.
        array_shift($shortest_string);
    }
    // If we made it here then we've run through everything
    usort($longest_common_substring, $sort_by_strlen);
    return array_pop($longest_common_substring);
}
```

I have written this up a little bit on my blog:

- [Find the longest common substring using PHP](http://www.christopherbloom.com/2011/02/24/find-the-longest-common-substring-using-php/) (24 Feb 2011)

Comment: This function will lowercase the output !! Be warned. There are other algorithms for this problem that do not suffer from this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at [Algorithm implementation/Strings/Longest common substring](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring#PHP) on Wikibooks. I haven't tested the PHP implementation but it seems to match the general algorithm on the Wikipedia page.

Comment: It is also incredibly slow. The dynamic programming algorithm listed on the wikipedia Longest_common_substring_problem page is very space efficient, but when implemented in php is more than twice as slow as a well written brute force solution, e.g. @Chrisbloom7 solution below.