# Merge string with common middle part

Tags: php, string

I have two strings:

```
$a = '/srv/http/projects/name';
$b = '/projects/name/some/dir';
```

And I would like to get a merged string with not repeated common part:

```
$c = '/srv/http/projects/name/some/dir';
```

Is there any effective way to get it ?

Comment: Will it always be a directory? Can we assume you'll know there will exist `/`?

Comment: Yes, it will be always a directory path with `/`.

Comment: It's a problem to find the largest common substring: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336605/how-can-i-find-the-largest-common-substring-between-two-strings-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing that I know of out-of-the-box. <strike>but this should do it:</strike>

```
function merge_overlap($left, $right) {
  // continue checking larger portions of $right
  for($l = 1; $l < strlen($right); $l++) {
    // if we no longer have a matching subsection return what's left appended
    if(strpos($left, substr($right, 0, $l)) === false) {
      return $left . substr($right, $l - 1);
    }
  }

  // no overlap, return all
  return $left . $right;
}
```

EDIT: Had an OBO, updated.

UPDATE: That was not the solution, strpos() is matching portions of text anywhere in the left path, should compare against tail.

Here is the correct implementation for my approach:

```
function merge_overlap($left, $right) {
  $l = strlen($right);
  // keep checking smaller portions of right
  while($l > 0 && substr($left, $l * -1) != substr($right, 0, $l))
    $l--;

  return $left . substr($right, $l);
}
```

Comment: Your method cuts off some of the path. `$a = '/srv/http/projects/name/http/';`, `$b = '/projects/name/http/some/dir';` so `/srv/http/projects/name/http/ome/dir ` gets returned. Notice the **ome**. This could be from my end, by try it out and let me know if you get similar results.

Comment: @Anthony Forloney: That was due to an OBO bug in my original post, already updated my answer with a fix, that new version works with your two values correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda ugly, and assumes your strings always start with '/'... but:

```
$a = '/srv/http/projects/name';
$b = '/projects/name/some/dir';

$merged = array_merge(explode('/', $a), explode('/', $b) );
$unique = array_unique($merged);

$c = implode('/', $unique);

print $c; // prints "/srv/http/projects/name/some/dir"
```

Comment: Does it work for a URL like `$a = '/srv/http/projects/name/http;` and `$b = '/projects/name/http/some/dir;`?

Comment: Nice approach.  This does assume that no directory name appears twice.  For a resulting path such as /www/one/two/www/ this would not work.

Comment: For `$a = '/name';` and `$b = '/projects/name/some/dir';` it will give `$c = '/name/projects/some/dir';` so it will not works properly.

Comment: @hsz - That example violates your requirements that there is a common middle part.

Answer (score 1):

```
function f($a, $b)
{
  for($i=0; count($a) > $i ; $i++)
  {
    if(strpos($b, substr($a, $i)) !== FALSE)
      return substr($a, 0, $i-1).$b;
  } 
  return $a.$b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function merge($a, $b) {
    // divide into path parts to compare the parts
    $start = preg_split('%/%', $a, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $end = preg_split('%/%', $b, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    // if the first part of the first path is in the second path than switch
    if(in_array($start[0], $end)) {
       $temp = $start;
       $start = $end;
       $end = $temp;
    }
    $parts = array();
    // get the index of the last part of the first path in the second path
    $index = array_search($start[count($start)-1], $end);

    // if the part exists, remove the first parts of the second path
    if($index !== false) {
        $parts = array_merge($start, array_slice($end, $index+1));
    }
    return '/' . join('/', $parts);
}


$a = '/srv/http/projects/name';
$b = '/projects/name/some/dir';

print merge($a, $b);
```

This gives me:

```
/srv/http/projects/name/some/dir
```

You might have to provide a default value or whatever if the path have no common part.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a "smart" way to do that. Just iterate over `$a` until all of the rightmost tokens match the same number of tokens at the beginning of `$b`.

Here I `explode()` both strings so that I can easily capture the right number of tokens via `array_slice()`.

```
$a = '/srv/http/projects/name/http';
$b = '/projects/name/http/some/dir';

var_dump(merge_path($a, $b));

function merge_path($path1, $path2)
{
    $p1 = explode('/', trim($path1,' /'));
    $p2 = explode('/', trim($path2,' /'));

    $len = count($p1);

    do
    {
        if (array_slice($p1, -$len) === array_slice($p2, 0, $len))
        {
            return '/'
                 . implode('/', array_slice($p1, 0, -$len))
                 . '/'
                 . implode('/', $p2);
        }
    }
    while (--$len);

    return false;
}
```