# built in function to combine overlapping string sequences in php?

Tags: php, string, merge, overlapping

Is there a built in function in PHP that would combine 2 strings into 1?

**Example**:

```
$string1 = 'abcde';
$string2 = 'cdefg';
```

Combine to get: `abcdefg`.

If the exact overlapping sequence and the position are known, then it is possible to write a code to merge them.

Comment: It's a problem to find the largest common substring: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336605/how-can-i-find-the-largest-common-substring-between-two-strings-in-php

Comment: We probably need a few sufficiently different test cases and expected results to form a [mcve].  With only one sample string, different developers may interpret different functionality with fringe cases.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**It's possible using [`substr_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) and [`strcspn()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcspn.php)**:

```
$string1 = 'abcde';
$string2 = 'cdefgh';

echo substr_replace($string1, $string2, strcspn($string1, $string2)); // abcdefgh
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try, it should help shorten my codes.

Comment: echo substr_replace('aacdabc', 'dabcg', strcspn('aacdabc', 'dabcg')); //dabcg

Answer (score 6):

I found the substr_replace method to return funny results.
Especially when working with url strings. I just wrote this function.
It seems to be working perfectly for my needs.
The function will return the longest possible match by default.

```
function findOverlap($str1, $str2){
  $return = array();
  $sl1 = strlen($str1);
  $sl2 = strlen($str2);
  $max = $sl1>$sl2?$sl2:$sl1;
  $i=1;
  while($i<=$max){
    $s1 = substr($str1, -$i);
    $s2 = substr($str2, 0, $i);
    if($s1 == $s2){
      $return[] = $s1;
    }
    $i++;
  }
  if(!empty($return)){
    return $return;
  }
  return false;
}

function replaceOverlap($str1, $str2, $length = "long"){
  if($overlap = findOverlap($str1, $str2)){
    switch($length){
      case "short":
        $overlap = $overlap[0];
        break;
      case "long":
      default:
        $overlap = $overlap[count($overlap)-1];
        break;
    }     
    $str1 = substr($str1, 0, -strlen($overlap));
    $str2 = substr($str2, strlen($overlap));
    return $str1.$overlap.$str2;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Usage to get the maximum length match:

```
echo replaceOverlap("abxcdex", "xcdexfg"); //Result: abxcdexfg
```

To get the first match instead of the last match call the function like this:

```
echo replaceOverlap("abxcdex", "xcdexfg", “short”); //Result: abxcdexcdexfg
```

To get the overlapping string just call:

```
echo findOverlap("abxcdex", "xcdexfg"); //Result: array( 0 => "x", 1 => "xcdex" )
```

Comment: +1 I would change `$s1 = substr($str1, $sl1-$i);` to: `$s1 = substr($str1, -$i);` - it would be more elegant ;) second, you might want to consider also checking overlap in the opposite direction: `findOverlap($str2, $str1);`

Comment: Was looking for something like this for a bit. Great solution! Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no builtin function, but you can easily write one yourself by using `substr` and a loop to see how much of the strings that overlap.

Comment: Thanks, I am just looking for a short cut to cut down on the code. But I guess it is not possible.