# Compare a part of 2 strings (PHP)?

Tags: php, substring, string-comparison

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Highlight the difference between two strings in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321294/highlight-the-difference-between-two-strings-in-php)

I have those strings for example:

*example **XY2**\r\n(system x)*

and

*something else **XY2***

As you see, only the XY2 is the same. Whats the best way to check if 2 strings have something in common, like XY2?

Thanks!

Comment: How long must the match be? The two strings have several one-char strings in common...

Comment: Variable length ... its not so easy, is it?

Answer (score 1):

you can try using [`similar_text`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) function. Not quiet what you need but can be helpful.

Look at this post on [finding largest common substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336605/how-can-i-find-the-largest-common-substring-between-two-strings-in-php).