# Compare two string with numbers if have similarity

Tags: php, function

I am looking for a function in PHP that can do a comparison of two strings with numbers. They should at least 5 same letters/number in **consecutive order**.

Example: 
`AD-2018-34567-234` and `cd 34567` 
both contains same letters/number = `34567`

OR

`10256` and `cd 10256` both contains `10256`

OR

`1234567890- rfwet043-123455-cd1234-sdf` and `4edgs-cd12340e-3ed`
both contains `cd1234`

Tried using this [function here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520646/how-to-check-a-partial-similarity-of-two-strings-in-php#answer-16521079) but doesn't meet my needs.

```
$str1 = "AD-2018-34567-234";
$str2 = "cd 34567";

$str3 = "10256";
$str4 = "cd 10256";

$str5= "1234567890-rfwet043-123455-cd1234-sdf";
$str6= "4edgs-cd12340e-3ed";

if(strpos($str1, $str2) !== false) {
    echo "matched";
}else{
    echo "not matched";
}

if(strpos($str3, $str4) !== false) {
    echo "matched";
}else{
    echo "not matched";
}

if(strpos($str5, $str6) !== false) {
    echo "matched";
}else{
    echo "not matched";
}
```

Tried also `strpos` all did not match.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find the Largest Common Substring between two strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336605/how-can-i-find-the-largest-common-substring-between-two-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you want by looping the find string and only using five charaters at the time to match with.

```
$str1 = ["AD-2018-34567-234","10256","1234567890-rfwet043-123455-cd1234-sdf"];
$str2 = ["cd 34567","cd 10256","4edgs-cd12340e-3ed"];

foreach($str1 as $key => $str){
    $find = $str2[$key];
    $l = strlen($find);
    $match = false;
    for($i=0; $i<=($l-5);$i++){ // loop the find string 
        //echo $str . " " . substr($find,$i, 5) . "\n"; // debug
        if(strpos($str, substr($find,$i, 5)) !== false) { // take five characters at the time and stros them
            $match = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($match){
        echo "match\n";
    }else{
        echo "no match\n";
    }
}
```

If you uncomment the line that is commented you will see how it works

https://3v4l.org/unp0D

---

```
$str1 = "AD-2018-34567-234";
$find = "cd 34567";
$l = strlen($find);

$match = false;
for($i=0; $i<=($l-5);$i++){ // loop the find string 
    //echo $str1 . " " . substr($find,$i, 5) . "\n"; // debug
    if(strpos($str1, substr($find,$i, 5)) !== false) { // take five characters at the time and stros them
        $match = true;
        break;
    }
}
if($match){
    echo "match\n";
}else{
    echo "no match\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Can give me a sample with only one value for $str1 and $str2?

Comment: @c.k Updated answer

Comment: Cool. Thank you @Andreas. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

tryout this solution

```
<?php
$str1 = "AD-2018-34567-234";
$str2 = "cd 34567";

$str3 = "10256";
$str4 = "cd 10256";

$str5= "1234567890-rfwet043-123455-cd1234-sdf";
$str6= "4edgs-cd12340e-3ed";

$val=similar_text($str1, $str2,$per);
if($val>=5){
    echo "Matched";
}else{
    echo "Not matched";
}

$val=similar_text($str3, $str4,$per);
if($val>=5){
    echo "Matched";
}else{
    echo "Not matched";
}

$val=similar_text($str5, $str6,$per);
if($val>=5){
    echo "Matched";
}else{
    echo "Not matched";
}
```

Comment: Similar_text doesn't require it to consecutive does it?

Comment: Yes it does not require it.